# how to Merge two cell on one cell

Tags: php, mysql

i have tow row that have the same data but only one cell Different than other like this :-

```
Customer Name   |   No Room   |   Room Type
 Maikle dived         2             single
 Maikle dived         1             double
```

So i wont to merge the Customer on one cell like this :-

```
Customer Name   |   No Room   |   Room Type
                      2             single
  Maikle dived            
                      1             double
```

how can i do this by PHP and mysql

Comment: no need to use mysql, you can customize your table while printing it...

Comment: Are you just trying to format the table like this on output?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Output formatting or database design? Save the `Customer Name` as reference (foreign key) to another table. This way your table looks like:
`Customer ID: 1 | No Room: 2 | Room Type: single` where the `Customer ID` is an reference to another table storing the name (and other, additional information)

Comment: i will try by mysql `select * from hotel , room , customer  where hotel.hotel_customer_id = customer.customer_id  and hotel.hotel_id = room.room_hotel_id` but it Repeated customer name

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to output it as HTML then do following:

```
 //$source should hold the data from DB
 $source = array(
   array('Maikle dived' => array('No Room' => 2, 'Room Type' => 'single'),
   array('Maikle dived' => array('No Room' => 1, 'Room Type' => 'double'),
 );

$result = array();

foreach($source as $item) {
    $user = key($item);
    $val  = current($item);

    if(!isset($result[$user])) {
        $result[$val] = array();
    }
    $result[$user][] = $val;
}
```

then you can loop through the $result to build html

```
foreach($result as $user => $vals) {
    echo $user;
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($vals as $val) {
        echo '<li>'.$val.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: how cant i but my result from DB to array ?? my query is `select * from hotel , room , customer where hotel.hotel_customer_id = customer.customer_id and hotel.hotel_id = room.room_hotel_id`